# Chainable Implementation for Moq

Tags: moq, method-chaining

Is there a chainable implementation of Moq out there? I was thinking that instead of this:

```
var mockSchedule = new Mock<Schedule>();
mockSchedule.SetupGet(x => x.Date).Returns(new DateTime(2011,6,1));
mockSchedule.SetupGet(x => x.Label).Returns("Schedule A");
```

I can call it like this:

```
var mockSchedule = 
    new Mock<Schedule>()
        .Which().SetupGet(x => x.Date).Returns(new DateTime(2011,6,1))
        .Which().SetupGet(x => x.Label).Returns("Schedule A");
```

or like this:

```
var mockSchedule =
    new Mock<Schedule>().
        .SetupGetWith(x => x.Date,new DateTime(2011,6,1))
        .SetupGetWith(x => x.Label,"Schedule A");
```

I could write these myself but if there's an existing implementation I'd rather not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of; there's the Moq v4 functional specifications.

```
var foo = Mock.Of<IFoo>(f =>
    f.Id == 1 &&
    f.Who == "me" &&
    f.GetBar(It.IsAny<string>()) == Mock.Of<IBar>(
        b => b.Name == "Fred"));
```

The documentation could be better. I've got a [short writeup on my blog](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2011/04/20/moq_v4_functional_specifications). See also [Old style imperative mocks vs moq functional specifications](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/old-style-imperative-mocks-vs-moq-functional-specifications/) and [this Moq Discussions thread](http://groups.google.com/group/moqdisc/browse_thread/thread/7c0477e3f4e6f400?pli=1).

Comment: Nice. The syntax doesn't seem very intuitive but it's definitely an improvement. I didn't see that in the QuickStart. How do you set CallBase and DefaultValue for this though?

Comment: I believe you have to use `Mock.Get(foo).CallBase();` or use the old syntax. See the discussion thread link above for more on this. And yes, currently this is not in the QuickStart.